# Determining whether or not a function is riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

### Background

I was tackling baby rudin chapter 6, when I started wondering what are the telltale signs of a function being integrable. Clearly if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist a partition $P$ on $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$ then it is integrable, but what if there exist a point $x\in [a,b]$ such that the minimum and maximum of $f$ around $x$ doesn't converge.

This question came up when analyzing the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$ which has the problem that the min and the max around every point in $\mathbb{R}$ stays constant So $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$ stay constant when taken over all permutations, which gives you lack of integratablity (since $U(P,f)\neq L(P,f)$). so I was wondering if a similar I idea could be conveyed with just one point.

### The problem

Say we have a bounded function $f$ with the property that around a single point $x$ there exist points in every neighborhood $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, points $y,y'$ such that $f(y)\geq c>c'\geq f(y')$. Would this imply that $f$ is non-integrable on any closed interval containing $x$?

### What I have done

I have personally tried playing with some examples namely:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x=\pm \frac{1}{2^n};n=1,2,\cdots\\ -1 & x=\pm\frac{1}{10^n};n=1,2,\cdots\\
x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ integrating on $[-1,1]$, and personally I am having trouble finding out whether or not this is integrable.

Comment: The following theorem of Lebesgue is very useful. The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[a,b]$ if and only if $f$ is bounded and the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$.

Comment: I think your statement of the problem is a bit off because $f(y)=c$ for $y<c$, $f(y)=c'$ for $y>c$ meets it.  I think you want to ensure that the over $c$ and under $c'$ points are mixed together, for example dense in $(x-\epsilon,x)$.  (And the theorem André Nicolas mentions, by the way, is Rudin 11.33.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for example the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ if $x\ne 0$, and say $0$ if $x=0$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[-1,1]$.  But in every neighbourhood of $0$ there exist points $y$ and $y'$ such that $f(y)=1$ and $f(y')=-1$.

**Remark:** The following theorem of Lebesgue is useful. The function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if it is bounded on the interval and the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Okay, having a hard time proving that $f(x)=sin(1/x)$ is integrable on the interval $[-1,1]$. How did you figure this part out, as finding $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$ of arbitrary partitions is a pain with $sin(1/x)$?

Comment: I did not write out a partition argument, since the Lebesgue Criterion settles things. But think of partitions with mesh size $\lt \delta/4$. In the "bad" part near $0$ the upper sum and lower sum differ by $\delta/2$, and in the rest they can be controlled, by continuity.